# err_connection_timed_out in chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Chrome does not load some websites and gives err_connection_timed_out. I have tried clearing cookies, the check box "use a proxy server for your LAN" is unchecked and I have tried uninstalled and reinstalled chrome and updating windows and security already. I have no luck on this issue.

The website just works fine on monzilla, but does not load on IE and chrome. Its happens to many computers in my work place after a windows update a few days ago.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue described and struggled to find a solution. But after I installed a web debugger (like Fiddler), websites load on Chrome.